# Gmail with oauth 2-legged authentication is it specific to domain id's

Tags: java, oauth, jakarta-mail

I find one [article](http://www.chilkatforum.com/questions/9368/oauth2-gmail-authentication-fails) related to oauth 2-legged authentication. I need to conform is it(Explanation about 2-legged authentication) right or wrong ? I did not find this answer any where, so I have a doubt, please clarify this doubt.
I need to send mail with  oauth token by using oauth 2-legged authentication, (while sending mail I used google domain name (xx@gmail.com)). please check [here](http://www.example-code.com/java/smtp_gmailOAuth2.asp) for article related code.

Comment: You're asking "is it right or wrong"; what does "it" refer to?  Everything said in that article?  I believe the article is generally correct, but perhaps there's some specific detail that you're asking about?  Have you seen the [JavaMail OAuth2 web page](https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/OAuth2)?

Comment: This line from article--> "This is where two-legged OAuth2 SHOULD solve the problem, but it doesn't. Not for consumer GMail accounts. It is possible with a Google Apps account where the email address is NOT a gmail.com email address." . I tried with XXX@gmail.com acounts, this is not working. shall I need to buy domain account in gmail(XX@mydomain.com)

Comment: As I understand it, if you own your own Google Apps domain, you can be an administrator in that domain, and you can access the accounts for any of the users in that domain by authenticating as the administrator instead of the user.  Would that solve whatever problem you have?